# Update value of an element in React component from iOS UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview, reactjs

I am trying to transfer data from native iOS app to a React (not react-native) web app running in a UIWebView.

I get a string from native viewcontroller and need to "inject" it into the value of an `<input>` element inside a React component class. I gave the element an `id` like so:

```
render() {
<div>
...
    <input id="iccid" type="text" name="iccid" pattern="\d*" onChange={this.iccidChanged.bind(this)} autoFocus />
...
</div>
}
```

Then using JavaScriptCore from iOS (Swift code) I run:

```
self.context = self.webView.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as? JSContext
self.context!.evaluateScript("document.getElementById('iccid').value='\(barcodeValue)';")
```

This seems work fine and I can see the value updated in the DOM inside the webview, problem is that my React `onChange` function (that validates the value and changes component state) *does not* fire as React does not interpret this as a change (probably because of DOM vs virtual DOM handling).

What's the correct way/best practice to update the element value from iOS AND get the React component to behave like user has typed it in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm supposing that you want to trigger an event when a barcode is scanned. Your iOS app probably doesn't need to know **where** the event should be dispatched (i.e. which input field and how). It should be enough just to signal the web view that a barcode has been scanned.

You can dispatch a custom DOM event to `window` and have some React component listen to that event.

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('barcodescan', {
  detail: {
    value: '(barcodeValue)'
  }
}))
```

You can then create a non-rendering component that will listen to the barcode event:

```
const BarcodeListener = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    onBarcodeScan: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },
  componentDidMount () {
    window.addEventListener('barcodescan', this.handleBarcodeScan)
  },
  componentWillUnmount () {
    window.removeEventListener('barcodescan', this.handleBarcodeScan)
  },
  render () {
    return null
  },
  handleBarcodeScan (e) {
    this.props.onBarcodeScan(e)
  }
})
```

Then, in your form, you can render the input alongside with the barcode event listener:

```
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <input ... />
        <BarcodeListener onBarcodeScan={this.handleBarcodeScan} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Then handle the barcode scan event separately.

Comment: Finally managed to solve this issue on my own by using a similar idea - I just added the event listener on the DOM element itself (not a dummy one) and used `new Event()` from the swift code. No need to create a dummy invisible element - but your suggestion will work too. Accepted as correct answer.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the dummy invisible element because it cleanly separates the concerns and allows BarcodeListener to be reused in other places. Having worked with very large React apps, I learned that the Single Responsibility Principle is most important. When components do more than one thing, it becomes hard to keep track of everything that happens inside it.